# How to get property values and msihandle from running installer into managed custom action (C#)

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

I created a deferred/system context custom action in installShield 2012 which calls a managed method. This assembly is stored in the binary table, although I can change to installed with the product if need be. I would like to pass a parameter to my managed method in order to:

1) get the values of public properties

2) maybe write to the windows installer log file

I have been using [this article](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/ManagedCA-Arguments.htm) as guidance, however I think it is too ambiguous to be very useful (or I just don't understand it). I have tried both their default method signature and my own. Its not clear what really happens if I use the default..for example it says it will call my method with the msihandle parameter, **but how am I supposed to get that msihandle in my managed code and do something useful with it??**

Are there any good examples of this out there that my searches are missing? I see little use in using managed custom actions if I cannot get something as simple as a property value.

Comment: DTF: var productName = session["ProductName"];

Comment: I still don't see how I can pass the 'Session' from the InstallShield CA method signature to the WindowsInstaller CA. For example I get error: Unexpected parameter type Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session encountered; passing string instead

Comment: email me at chrpai@iswix.com and we can do a 15-30 minute screen sharing session where I'll get you started. (No Charge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put,  Flexera made a good effort at managed custom actions at a time when others were refusing to try.  But their infrastructure has been outclassed by Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).   This is the gold standard for managed code custom actions.  And bets of all, you can use it with InstallShield because it outputs DLL's that just appear as native Type1 MSI DLL custom actions.

Comment: It certainly seems like the WiX is the winner, and I plan on taking new projects to it. " it outputs DLL's that just appear as native Type1 MSI DLL". Are you saying that InstallShield converts my managed code to native at design-time?

Comment: I'm going to try the MsiInterop class you posted in your article here: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/12/managed-code-can-access-msihandle_10.html. If I follow your steps, I should be able to get the msi handle into my managed code and use GetProperty and SetProperty even when this is called from deferred / system context custom action, right? Is it also possible to expand the Session class to support things like writing to the log, too? (I couldn't find any useful doc on for logging with the windows installer SDK, so I have my doubts)

Comment: Amendment:The MsiInterop class was something someone mentioned in your article

Comment: You should ignore every managed custom action article I ever wrote prior to the release of DTF. DTF has the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller assembly that makes MsiInterop.cs look like a grammer school project. :)

Comment: DTF encapsulates the managed assembly with a native DLL.  At runtime it self extracts, fires up the CLR and creates a named pipe between the two to marshall API calls back and forth.  It's 100% compatible with MSI and thefore InstallShield.

Comment: I've been reviewing DFT and this looks promising. Thank for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

The document [Managed Custom Action Sample](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=7220) covers most uses of InstallShield's managed code custom action support. You can find it and the associated sample code in the `Samples\WindowsInstaller\Managed Custom Actions` subfolder of your InstallShield installation.

If you want to use the `MSIHANDLE` directly, use the non-custom signature, declare a `UInt32` parameter for your function, and P/Invokes for calls like `MsiGetProperty`, `MsiProcessMessage`, and so forth, passing your `UInt32` handle to these P/Invokes. If you want to use the available `InstallShield.Interop.Msi` to provide the P/Invokes, the Managed Custom Action Sample covers this too; including sample usage of a helper class `CustomActionHandle` shown in `MsiWrapper.cs`.

If you'd rather use the custom signature support, you can just create a string parameter for each property you want to pass to your function, and specify the properties to pass in each position. Unless you also pass the MsiHandle, it will not be possible to write to the log file in this case.

Comment: This answer is intended to directly answer the original questions; it is not intended to dispute DTF's appropriateness.

Comment: Using the CustomActionHandle.GetProperty("CustomActionData") still does not seem to be able to retrieve anything useful (I am basically using the same EchoCustomActionData(Int32) method from the example, but in my own assembly).  Even using the sample as it came out of the box, the EchoCustomActionData messagebox shows nothing...I think I'm expecting it show all of the properties, right? Last, It also doesn't look like I can actually write to the msi log file . All I see is Msi.EnableLog, but how do I write to the log? I've been through the SDK docs, its not obvious if this is even possible

Comment: I see, I need to create a SetProperty CA. Still not sure about how to use logging though.

Comment: SetProperty is useful for lightweight, simple custom action data.  For more see: http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html  (note the customactiondata dictionary ... you don't have to use JSON but it is cool )